# How to mock windsor container in order to test registration

Tags: c#, nunit, castle-windsor, moq

For educational purposes, how should I setup a mock of IWindsorContainer, so I can unit test performed registration?

Suppose I have a method like this:

```
public void MakeRegistration<S, T>(IWindsorContainer container)
   where S : class
   where T : class, S
{
   container.Register(Component.For<S>().ImplementedBy<T>().LifeStyle.Transient);
}
```

I would like to write a unit test for it, using Moq:

```
var container = new Mock<IWindsorContainer>(MockBehavior.Strict);
container.Setup(c => c.Register(
      Component.For<IFoo>()
      .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
      .LifeStyle.Transient));

var registrar = new MyRegistrar();
registrar.MakeRegistration<IFoo, Foo>(container.Object);
```

The above fails, as expected, but I'm curious how to properly test it.

I could use real container instead of a mock, and verify that it resolves 2 different instances of the class, but I consider it not "pure" unit test, as it actually relies on the workings of external code (windsor container itself).

As I said, this is theoretical, so if it's needed or not is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: If you test registration on fake container, what is the purpose of this test? It tests nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an assertion that the implementation `Foo` was registered against the service `IFoo` that would be the pure test (Example using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) as I have not used moq for some time).

```
[ Test ]
public void Should_register_implemenation_of_Foo_for_service_IFoo()
{
    var container = Substitute.For<IWindsorContainer>();

    container.Register( Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>() );

    container.Received().Register( Arg.Is<IRegistration[]>(x => Test(x) ));

}

private bool Test(IRegistration[] registrations)
{
    var fooRegistration = (ComponentRegistration<IFoo>) registrations[ 0 ];

    return fooRegistration.Implementation == typeof(Foo);
}
public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo : IFoo {}
```

I know you have said that the question theoretical but it is important to ask the following question so that those new to TDD assume that you must do things this way.

*Should a test dictate **how a component achieves it's goal** or should it just test **that a component actually achieves it's goal**?*

IMO I feel that there is more value in writing an integration test that shows that the wire up is correct over making sure that certain methods are called on dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right way, I should intercept IRegistrations passed to Register method, and inspect this.

Comment: To answer your other statement, if the requirement is "Should register as LifeStyle.Transient", thanm what I'm asking for makes sense from TDD POV.

Comment: You could argue though that is a behavior so as long as you have some acceptance criteria to test against it shouldn't matter if your lifestyle is transient or not just as long as it works. If your criteria forces you to switch to a transient lifestyle then fine but should it dictate that you should use a transient lifestyle? This is where you step away from TDD and start looking at BDD. A test could be "Should not return same instance of xyz", the difference is your test doesn't say you must use a transient lifestyle but it does say I want a different object each time.

Comment: I agree with you, but the problem is that I can't test this "behavior" w/o using the real container. Thanks for the pointers.